# Optimization: show that $\min \sum_{i \in I}\min f_i(y_i) = \min \sum_{i \in I}f_i(y_i)$

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, maxima-minima

I am working on an optimization problem where I need to minimize the sum of a collection of minimization problems. The problem currently has this form:

$$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^m} \sum_{i \in I} g_i(x),$$

where

$$g_i(x)=\sum_{i \in I}\min_{y_i \in D_i(x)} f_i(y_i)$$

In this problem, I am trying to choose a vector $x$ which in turn helps determine the feasible regions $D_i(x)$ for a number of subproblems indexed by $i$. The decision variables $y_i$ for each subproblem are vectors of real numbers. Combining these problems gives a single, two-level "min min" problem:

$$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^m} \sum_{i \in I}\min_{y_i \in D_i(x)} f_i(y_i).$$

It seems clear that this is equivalent to the following single-level problem:

$$\min_{\substack{x \in \mathbb{R}^m \\ y_i \in D_i(x), \space \forall i \in I}} \sum_{i \in I}f_i(y_i).$$

The intuition behind the equivalency is that when solving the single-level problem, one would have to choose the $y_i$ vectors that minimize each $f_i(y_i)$, since those in turn will minimize the overall problem. But that's not a very satisfying "proof." Is there a more explicit way to prove this?

A stackexchange answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/231880/425405 says "extremizations of the same type ... can be combined into a single quantifier/extremization." Is this a standard theorem that I can quote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note first that
$$\min_{x\in\mathbb R^n}\min_{y_i\in D(x)\,\forall i\in I} = \min_{y_i\in D(x)\,\forall i\in I, x\in\mathbb R^n}$$
Given that, it suffices to show that for *all* $x$,
$$\sum_{i\in I}\min_{y_i\in D(x)} f_i(y_i) = \min\left\{\sum_{i\in I}f_i(y_i):y_i\in D(x),\,\forall i\in I\right\}.$$
In other words, removing the explicit dependence on $x$ we want to show:
$$\sum_{i\in I}\min_{y_i\in D} f_i(y_i) = \min\left\{\sum_{i\in I}f_i(y_i):y_i\in D,\,\forall i\in I\right\}.$$

Then the point is that the minimum of a sum of functions **of distinct variables** is the sum of the minima.
Let
$$f(x,y)=g(x)+h(y).$$
If $g(x_0)\le g(x)$ for all $x$ and $h(y_0)\le h(y)$ for all $y$ then
$$f(x_0,y_0)=g(x_0)+h(y_0)\le g(x)+h(y)= f(x,y)$$
for all $(x,y)$.

More generally if $f(y_1,\dots,y_k)=\sum g_i(y_i)$ and $g_i(y_{i,0})\le g(y_i)$ for all $i$ and $y_i$ then
$$f(y_{1,0},\dots,f(y_{k,0})\le f(y_1,\dots,y_k)$$
for all $y_1,\dots,y_k$.

Comment: Thanks! I think the key part is to break it into two steps -- the minimum of the sum of independent functions is the sum of the minima of the individual functions, as you showed. Once that's established, then it's pretty easy to combine the two minimize operations.